Why a blank is not getting considered as a blank in my program?
I am learning C from K&R. In it below question has been asked:

Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

While trying some approaches for this question I wrote below code but I am not able to understand why it outputs what it outputs.
int main(){
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        if (c == ' ')
            printf('test');
            putchar(c);
}

My understanding was that for input 'A B C D' the output would be 'Atest Btest Ctest Dtest' to my surprise its just 'ABCD'.
Can anyone explain what is happening here ?

This question is similar to: Can these C codes be refactored this way?. C is not python. C ignores indentation. You specify grouping with curly braces.

Change printf('test') to printf("test").  Your compiler should have warned about the first argument not being a string.  It's a typo.  Also, learn to use else rather than repeating the complement of the if condition.

Unlike Python, grouping of statements in C isn't dictated by indentation.  Each group statement such as while or if only applies to the next statement.  So what you have is more like this:
int main(){
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
    if (c == ' ')
        printf('test');
    putchar(c);
}

You need to use braces to group multiple statements, and in fact should use them in all cases of such statements for clarity:
int main(){
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            putchar(c);
        }
        if (c == ' ') {
            printf("test");
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

Also note that the above call to printf uses double quotes instead of single quotes, as double quotes are used for strings and single quotes for single characters.
Better yet:
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            putchar(c);
        } else {
            printf("test");
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

To use if...else rather than multiple if statements with opposite conditions.
Better still, to avoid repetition:
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            printf("test");
        }
        putchar(c);
    }

